# Open ball for the distance $\inf\{1,|x-y|\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

By definition $B_{d}(x_0,r)=\{y\in R, d(x_0,y)<r\}$

then $B_{d}(x_0,r)=\{y\in R, \inf\{1,|x-y|\}<r\}=\{y\in R,\begin{cases} |x-y|<r; ~\text{if}~ |x-y|<1\\ 1<r,~~~~~~~~~~~\text{if}~1<|x-y|\end{cases}\}$

How to continue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $r>1$ then $B_{d}(x_0,r)=\mathbb{R}$. In fact if $y\in\mathbb{R}$ then $d(x_0,y)\leq 1<r$.

On the other hand, if $0<r\leq 1$ then $B_{d}(x_0,r)=(x_0-r,x_0+r)$.

Comment: the distance is very clear , $d(x,y)=\inf\{1,|x-y|\}$ hpow you get $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: what about when $r<1$ ?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Any more doubts?

Comment: i don't understand how you do in the case r<1

Comment: If $r\leq 1$ then $d(x,y)=\inf\{1,|x-y|\}<r\leq 1$ implies that $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Any more doubts?